# You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app

Tags: reactjs, version, react-router-dom

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

//Layouts
import HomeLayoutRoute from "./components/layouts/HomeLayout";

//components
import Home from './components/Home';
//import Dashboard from './components/Dash';

// Routing
import PrivateRoute from "./components/routing/PrivateRoute";

// Screens
import PrivateScreen from "./components/loginscreens/PrivateScreen";
import LoginScreen from "./components/loginscreens/LoginScreen";
import RegisterScreen from "./components/loginscreens/RegisterScreen";
import ForgotPasswordScreen from "./components/loginscreens/ForgotPasswordScreen";
import ResetPasswordScreen from "./components/loginscreens/ResetPasswordScreen";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="app">
        <Routes> 
          <HomeLayoutRoute path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/" element={<PrivateScreen/>} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<LoginScreen/>} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterScreen/>} />
          <Route path="/forgotpassword" element={<ForgotPasswordScreen/>}/>
          <Route path="/passwordreset/:resetToken" element={<ResetPasswordScreen/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is my App.js file
This is the Error :
Error: You cannot render a  inside another . You should never have more than one in your app.

This code works with React-Router-Dom Version 5, But When I move to React-Router-Dom version 6 this error came.

Comment: The code you've shown looks fine; it just has one router (the `<BrowserRouter>` element). So it's probably in one of those other components where the duplicate router is.

Comment: Can you check the App.js code which I have used in React Router version 5

Comment: It's a design decision. Nested routers are no longer supported in version 6.

Comment: The possible error is with <BrowserRouter>. You might have included this element in your Index.js and in your App.js both. You should keep it in any one file.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Set up your index.js file similar to this

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={ <App /> }>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Then remove BrowserRouter in your App.js file

```
const App = () => {
  return (
      <div className="app">
        <Routes> 
          <HomeLayoutRoute path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/" element={<PrivateScreen/>} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<LoginScreen/>} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterScreen/>} />
          <Route path="/forgotpassword" element={<ForgotPasswordScreen/>}/>
          <Route path="/passwordreset/:resetToken" element={<ResetPasswordScreen/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: `HomeLayoutRoute` and `PrivateRoute` are invalid children of the `Routes` component. Only `Route` and `React.Fragment` are valid children of the `Routes` component.

Answer (score 9):

Try this!

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js

Note that you need to import { Routes, Route } instead of { Route } (as it was in previous versions). Also, note that on the App.js file, it is not necessary to import BrowserRouter again.

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import AllPages from "./pages/AllPages";
import NewContactsPage from "./pages/ContactsPage";
import FavoritesPage from "./pages/Favorites";

function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<AllPages />} />
        <Route path="/new-contacts" element={<NewContactsPage />} />
        <Route path="/favorites" element={<FavoritesPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: react_dom_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.render is not a function

Answer (score 6):

One possible error might be with

> **`<BrowserRouter>`**

You might have included this element in your `App.js` and in your  `Index.js` both.

You can check and keep this element in any one file so **nesting of duplicate routes** will be removed.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, but, **YOU DON'T NEED TO CHANGE THE VERSION**

If You're working with **React v.18** You must update the rendering @ index.js to the propper and documented way to render root/app file... please visit this link for more details: [Updates to Client Rendering APIs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-client-rendering-apis)

in your **index.js**:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { App } from './App';
const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App tab='home' />);
```

in your **App.jsx**:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { AppNav } from "./Components/AppNav";
import { Home } from "./Pages/Home";
import { Users } from "./Pages/Users";
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <AppNav />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/users" element={<Users />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
```

To see a working sample/code please visit my GitHub repo: [github.com/lodela/React18](https://github.com/lodela/React18_seed)

Comment: Why am I having the error: "Property 'tab' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'."? The version of react is 18. Thnx in advance

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error... could you please share your code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `react-router-dom` version 5.3.0 and I can't find an exported member named 'Routes'. Not sure if this member comes from an older version of `react-router-dom`.

That said, I think you might want to replace `<Routes>` with `<Switch>`.

`<Switch>` renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="app">
    <Switch> 
      <HomeLayoutRoute path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/" element={<PrivateScreen/>} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginScreen/>} />
      <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterScreen/>} />
      <Route path="/forgotpassword" element={<ForgotPasswordScreen/>}/>
      <Route path="/passwordreset/:resetToken" element={<ResetPasswordScreen/>}/>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

(https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch)

**Edit:**
As for the error: "You cannot render a  inside another . You should never have more than one in your app" -> I think it might be related to the problem I mentioned above but it can also be because you have a duplicated router inside another. (E.g. the component `<ForgotPasswordScreen/>` contains another `<Route>` element inside).

Comment: In version 6  <Switch> replace with <Routes> .

Comment: You are right, I was not aware of that. And it seems that you can have nested Routes as well, so this error doesn't make a lot of sense for this version. Can you double-check in your package-lock/yarn.lock that your project is really using react-router-dom v6?
Also, keep in mind that v6 it's still under active development.

Answer (score 1):

As of React Router version 6, nested routers will not be supported. So for example, you can't use `<MemoryRouter>` inside `<BrowserRouter>`.

Please see:
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7375

Answer (score 1):

after degrading react-router-dom@6 to react-router-dom@5 useNavigate is not working.
useNavigate only works in react-router-dom@6

Answer (score 0):

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

//Layouts
import HomeLayoutRoute from "./components/layouts/HomeLayout";

//components
import Home from './components/Home';
//import Dash from './components/DashBoard';

// Routing
import PrivateRoute from "./components/routing/PrivateRoute";

// Screens
import PrivateScreen from "./components/loginscreens/PrivateScreen";
import LoginScreen from "./components/loginscreens/LoginScreen";
import RegisterScreen from "./components/loginscreens/RegisterScreen";
import ForgotPasswordScreen from "./components/loginscreens/ForgotPasswordScreen";
import ResetPasswordScreen from "./components/loginscreens/ResetPasswordScreen";


const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Routes>
          <HomeLayoutRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={PrivateScreen} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginScreen} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterScreen} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/forgotpassword"
            component={ForgotPasswordScreen}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/passwordreset/:resetToken"
            component={ResetPasswordScreen}
          />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is the Code I have used with React-Router-Dom Version 5 I think problem with the Version 6

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is working for you do this
change the version but first erase the react-router-dom:6.something dependency from package.json folder and then

1). Uninstall Previous Version-
npm uninstall react-router-dom
2). Install Older version-
npm install react-router-dom@5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

don't use this BrowserRouter and this `createBrowserRouter` you need just one of them  in v6

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today and the issue was due to the fact in the app.js file I was importing:

*import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';*

while in a child component I was importing Link as follows:

*import { BrowserRouter as Link } from "react-router-dom";*

Took me a while to realise the issue. Instead Link should of been imported like:

*import { Link } from "react-router-dom";*

React should really have a better way of reporting this.

Answer (score -3):

We found that this problem happens when we use React Router version 6. In this version, nested routers are not supported. So, we uninstalled version 6 and installed version 5 to solve this issue quickly.

Uninstall version 6:

```
npm uninstall react-router-dom
```

Install version 5:

```
npm install react-router-dom@5.3.0
```

Comment: This is very unhelpful. The goal is to resolve this with version 6.