# <Router> inside another <Router>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm pretty new to React and react-router-dom (v6) and I stumbled on an error: "Error: You cannot render a `<Router>` inside another `<Router>`. You should never have more than one in your app."

While there's a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69828516/you-cannot-render-a-router-inside-another-router-you-should-never-have-more) I didn't find the answer I was looking for. As of right now I just have this code:

**Header.tsx**:

```
import './Header.min.css';
import { FaDumbbell } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { AiOutlineHome } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { useState } from 'react';
import App from '../../App';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
} from 'react-router-dom';


export default function Header() {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('Sign Up');
  return (
    <header id = "wrapper">
      <h1><span>Fit</span>ify <FaDumbbell /></h1>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <nav>
              <ul id = "nav_links">
                <li id = "home">
                  <Link to = "/"><AiOutlineHome id = 'house' />Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li className = "rest">{status}</li>
                <li className = "rest">Stats</li>
                <li className = "rest">Leaderboards</li>
                <li className = "rest">Goals</li>
              </ul>
            </nav>

            <Routes>
              <Route path = "/" element = {<App />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </Router>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Comment: Sooo.... Use only one router?

Comment: the router i believe needs to be at the root of your application, not just within a header

Comment: don't use `<Routes>` inside `<Router>`, remove the `<Router>` from your code & it will work

Comment: Is the error message and description not explanatory enough? Don't render more than one router and certainly don't render a second router within a router.

Comment: @Dhruv when your suggestion is followed, a new error appears: "Uncaught Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>." I am not sure this is the resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the router only one time in your apps. You use the Router in the parent component like the App component. you can delete the nested router then this problem is solved.

Comment: @AngelescuHoria How did you solve it? Care to elaborate?